# Frame by frame Play / Stop video file, in tkinter

Tags: python, video, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to start / stop a video file in tkinter on a raspberry pi, using python 3.

I need the video to start from the beginning every time an infrared sensor is LOW (broken) and stop as soon as the sensor is HIGH again. Ideally the video should be inside a tkinter canvas so that I can display other elements on the screen at the same time (for example a loading bar).

I managed to get everything running except for the video, which runs as soon as the sensor is detected, but it freezes all other process (for example the loading bar) and it does not stop when the sensor is HIGH.

here is a simplified (and unchecked) version of the code for you the get an idea of the general structure (the real code is much longer):

```
import tkinter as TK
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(14, GPIO.IN)

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.config(background = 'black', cursor = 'none')
        self.background = TK.Canvas(root, width = 1024, height = 600, bg = 'black')
        self.background.pack()

        self.ext = 0
        self.trial = 0
        self.infrared()

    def infrared(self):
        if (GPIO.input(14) == False):
            self.makebar()

            if (self.ext == 0):
                self.runvideo()

        else:
            os.system("killall omxplayer.bin")
            self.ext = 0

        self.root.after(16, self.infrared)

    def runvideo(self):
        os.system("omxplayer /home/pi/Desktop/testvideo.m4v")

    def makebar():
        self.stimulus_rect = TK.Canvas(root, width = 1024, height = 50, bg= 'white')
            if self.ext < 1000
                self.ext = self.ext + 10
                self.stimulus_rect.create_rectangle(0, 0, self.ext, 50, fill="red")
                self.stimulus_rect.place(x=0, y=0, anchor="new")
            else:
                self.trial = self.trial + 1
                self.ext = 0

root = TK.Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

From what I was able to find online: 
1) tkinter might be coupled with opencv to achieve this, but it does not look like installing opencv on the raspberry pi is a straightforward operation; 
2) In general options involving "os" seem to be bound to fail in what I want to achieve.

I couldn't find a clean way of doing this. My dream scenario would be to load into a canvas the video frames one by one and do so at 60hz (screen frequency). I would then check the sensor at exactly the same frequency and prevent the next frame to be loaded if the sensor is not broken. In pseudocode this would look like this

```
def infrared(self):
    if (GPIO.input(14) == False):
        self.makebar()

        if (self.ext == 0):
            self.runvideo()

    else:
        self.video.stop
        self.ext = 0
        self.frame = 0

    self.root.after(16, self.infrared)

def runvideo(self):
    self.frame = self.frame + 1
    video.run("testvideo.m4v", self.frame)
```

Any idea on how to achieve this in tkinter on a raspberry pi?

thanks
ant

Answer (score 0):

After a week of research and trials and errors this is how I currently achieve what I needed (in pseudocode):

```
#### PSEUDOCODE ####         
from subprocess import Popen  # this library is used to open the video file


class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.moviestart = False

    self.movieduration = 130000
    self.movie = "/home/pi/Desktop/test.mp4"

    def infrared(self):
        if (GPIO.input(IR) == False):
            if not self.moviestart:
                self.makevideo()  # Call the function to start the video
            self.moviestart = True  # Flag that the video has started
            self.moviestop = False  # Flag that the video is currently playing
            self.root.after(self.videoduration,
                            self.stopvideo)  # manually call the stop video function 
            # to stop the video after 13 seconds (video's length). 
            # I could not find a more elegant way of doing this, unfortunately. 
        else:
            self.clear_screen()

    self.root.after(self.refreshIR, self.infrared)


def makevideo(self):
    # popen will open the movie in a window of the size I specified, 
    # so that other element from tkinter can be placed on top of the movie window
    omxc = Popen(['omxplayer', self.movie, '--win', "0 30 800 450"])


def stopvideo(self):
    self.moviestart = False  # flag that movie has been stopped       
    if (self.moviestop == False):  # check if the movie is currently playing
        try:  # this is a cheap workaround other problems I had, do not try this at home
            os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')  # this literally kills any omxplayer instance 
            # currently open
            self.moviestop = True  # flag that the movie is not playing at the moment 
        except:
            pass
```

I hope this can be useful to anybody else with similar problems. I will update the answer if I find a better solution. For now this works good enough.